# PHP Mysql While loop for addition

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, where-clause

I have this field on my database

`email, addition` so what i want is that `WHERE email='$email'` it will look that the data user had for addition. now for addition field we have `100,100,1000`

how can i compute this with the `echo 1200`

my code is NOTE this is just a sample scriptcode i can't copy and paste my code here because it was long. so if you find typo error ignore it.

```
$sql = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = '$email' ") or die(mysql_error());
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql) ){
   echo $row[addition] ++;
}
```

yes i know its not correct format. what should i change? do i need to use for or foreach? in order to add those computation?

tghanks

Comment: You should normalize your database first. Look it up on google.

Comment: Without code no one helps you becuase what you are done it is not clear to them wants help you

Comment: Alright thank you so much, next time will complete the code

Comment: some people had a good understanding while some are so slow. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somthing like?

```
$sql = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = '$email' ") or die(mysql_error());

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql) ) {
  $iAdditionSum = 0;
  $aAddition = explode(',', $row['addition']);

  foreach($aAddition as (int) $iAddition) {
    $iAdditionSum += $iAddition;
  }

  echo $iAdditionSum;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

with correct (normalized) data structure you can do:

```
SELECT SUM(addition) AS total FROM users WHERE email = '$email'
```

if you store it as csv in a column as Ignas says in his commentes,
you can either fix your database structure or use php:

```
$sum = array_sum(explode(',', $row['addition']));
```

Comment: Thanks that was im looking for very simple answer with so much knowledge NOT a waste of TIME... thank you sir.

Comment: array_sum() ... nice, completely overlooked that function :)

Comment: @CD001 One of the best thing with answering questions on SO is that you can see how other people solves the same problem, and learn new ways to do the stuff you alredy know